# How can we solve the following system of integral equations

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-optimization, lp-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $I$ be a finite nonempty set
- $p,q_j$ be probabiliy density functions on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ for $j\in I$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $\sigma_{ij}:E^2\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E^{\otimes2}$-measurable for $i,j\in I$ with $\sigma_{ij}(x,y)=\sigma_{ji}(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in E$ and $i,j\in I$ and $$\sum_{j\in I}\int\lambda({\rm d}y)q_j(y)\sigma_{ij}(x,y)=1\tag1$$ for all $x\in E$ and $i\in I$
- $g\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$
- $\Lambda,w_i\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ for $i\in I$
- $\alpha>0$

> I want to solve the following system of equations for $(w_i)_{i\in I}$: $$\sum_{j\in I}\int\lambda({\rm d}y)q_j(y)\sigma_{ij}(x,y)\frac2{e^{\alpha\left(w_i(x)p(x)q_j(y)-w_j(y)p(y)q_i(x)\right)}+1}|g(x)-g(y)|^2+\Lambda(x)=0\tag2$$ for all $x\in E$ and $i\in I$ and $$\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1\tag3.$$

How can we do that? Is there an easy trick to separate the $w_i(x)$ term in $(1)$?

Comment: could you include a dirac delta function in the integral $\delta \left( -1 + \sum w_i \right)$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I need to admit that I'm not soure what you mean. Maybe you can elaborate on your idea.

Comment: i've used dirac delta functions to impose constraints on integrals modeling random walk ... to be honest, the very first line of your question immediately puts me into the zone of being unqualified to answer your question ... my mind instantly goes numb when I see "measure space" and a triple of involving a capital script letter and a greek letter ... measure space is either so abstract a concept that my small brain cannot grasp it, or so basic a concept that I'm overthinking it ... I have yet to read a satisfactory "measure theory for dummies" that leaves me feeling in the know

Comment: @phdmba7of12 How would you add the dirac delta function in your intuition? Maybe I can put your idea into a rigorous form.

Comment: for an example of how the delta function can be used to enforce a constraint, see the appendix of my paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13303776_Gaussian-approximation_formalism_for_evaluating_decay_of_NMR_spin_echoes